# Using a dictionary to replace characters in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have the following dictionary:

```
clues = {'A': '#', 'N': '%', 'M': '*'}
```

I also have the following list:

```
puzzle = ['#+/084&"', '#3w#%#+', '8%203*','']
```

How can I replace the items from the list (i.e. by referencing the values from 'clues') with the keys in 'clues' so it would now appear the following way:

```
puzzle = ['A+/084&"', 'A3wANA+', '8N203M','']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
puzzle = ['#+/084&"', '#3w#%#+', '8%203*','']
clues = {'A': '#', 'N': '%', 'M': '*'}
answer = []
for p in puzzle:
    for dest,src in clues.items():
        p = p.replace(src,dest)
    answer.append(d)
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a translation map from your dictionary, then use [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
try:
    # Python 3
    maketrans = str.maketrans
except AttributeError:
    # Python 2
    from string import maketrans

m = maketrans(''.join(clues.values()), ''.join(clues))
result = [s.translate(m) for s in puzzle]
```

This does assume the values in `clues` are unique. `str.translate()` is by far the fastest method to map single characters to other single characters.

Demo (using Python 2.7):

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> clues = {'A': '#', 'N': '%', 'M': '*'}
>>> puzzle = ['#+/084&"', '#3w#%#+', '8%203*', '']
>>> m = maketrans(''.join(clues.values()), ''.join(clues))
>>> [s.translate(m) for s in puzzle]
['A+/084&"', 'A3wANA+', '8N203M', '']
```

Comment: +1 I copied the answer to clipboard, opened this tab, I see 1 new answer popping up.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
for key, value in clues.iteritems():
    puzzle = [ a.replace(value,key) for a in puzzle]
```

To test it:

```
>>> clues = {'A': '#', 'N': '%', 'M': '*'}
>>> puzzle = ['#+/084&"', '#3w#%#+', '8%203*','']
>>> for key, value in clues.iteritems():
...     puzzle = [ a.replace(value,key) for a in puzzle]
...
>>> puzzle
['A+/084&"', 'A3wANA+', '8N203M', '']
```